# codename one build is redirecting to some other account

Tags: codenameone

Whenever I try iOS debug build, the ipa is being sent to some expired account that I heve not set so far. I have my own codename one account and want netbeans to send these builds to my account only.

NOTE: I am using Netbeans on Mac 10.9 machine.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Changing accounts is against the Codename One terms of service and by doing so you are risking banning.

Assuming this is a one time thing you can login to the old account and change the password there. Then send a new build.

Comment: I have my own account in codename one. Have installed Netbeans for mac. Created a sample and tried to "Send iOS Debug Build". Where to set the codename one account userid to get the build to that account. In other words, while setting up netbeans or any codename one project in mac, is there any place or directory where we need to save codename credentials?

Comment: When you send the build the first time a window should pop and ask you for the credentials. I assume you were doing something on another Mac desktop and the window hid behind something. Just cancel the build and send again, this time wait for the dialog to appear. After that the password/email will be associated and you won't need to do that again.